# Need to Upload VHD's to Azure? Best Practice?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

So im pretty new to Azure, but we don't have a solid backup for our VHD's. What's the best way to set up some "weekly" upload for VHD's that have changed for instance? We have about 3-4 TB's worth.

We won't be accessing the VHD's....but simply need them as a backup. So will the Azure blob storage work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Backup will serve you better. Actually it got updated this week with new features:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/03/31/azure-backup-announcing-new-pricing-model-for-tco-reduction/

More Info:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/backup/

Comment: Will I just store it under "blob" storage? Even if it's a VHD?

Comment: using Azure Backup or not, yes.